# Альтернатива pack() из php в C++

Tags: php, c++

Здравствуйте, раньше не сталкивался с C++ и бинарными данными, но есть код на php, нечто вроде `$Command = Pack( 'c*', 0xFE, 0xFD, $Command, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 )`... Вообще что это за символы вида 0x01, и как реализовать подобный код на C++... Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: @splite, вот 0xFD в Вашем примере меня смущает. Если бы там было 0xFF, то пример (на русском) был бы следующим:

   Добавить в начало текста, закодированного в UTF-16BE BOM, а в конец байты с значениями 1,2,3,4

На C/C++ в предположении, что результат (t) в  куче, а Command это байты с UTF-16, завершающиеся 0-м, текст мог бы выглядеть так:

     size_t len = getUtf16Len(Command);
     char  *t = (char *)malloc(len+8);
     if (t) {
       t[0] = 0xfe; t[1] = 0xff; // у Вас 0xfd
       memcpy(t+2,Command,len);
       for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) t[len+i] = i;
       t[i++] = 0; t[i] = 0;
     }

Comment: А что меняет 0xFD в моём примере? Или 0xFE 0xFD это какая-то комбинация?

Comment: @splite, 0xfe,0xfd это неизвестная (по крайней мере для меня), хотя вполне возможно, осмысленная комбинация байт. 

А вот комбинация 0xfe,0xff очень напоминает BOM (Byte Order Mark) для кодировки текста UTF-16BE (подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.BA_.D0.B1.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вначале нужно поправить знания.

- первым долгом читаем, что такое [байт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) и [бит](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82). Узнаем, о том, что в байте 8 бит и байт имеет 256 значений.
- Потом читаем о том, что такое [шестнадцатеричная система счисления](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и как оно выглядит в с++ (в начале дописывается `0x`).
- Дальше нужно почитать о [порядке байт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

А после этого всего станет все понятно.

Теперь нужно разобраться, что php код делает. `c*` говорит, что нужно в виде массива char сделать. В с++ это будет либо `char []` либо `std::vector<char>`.
php скрывает много разных преобразований, но другие заставляет делать руками.

```
std::vector<char> command;
char start [] = { 0xFE, 0xFD };
char stop [] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
command.insert(command.end(), start, start + 2);
command.insert(command.end(), com, len_com);
command.insert(command.end(), stop, stop + 4);
```

В коде осталось две неизвестные переменные - `com` и `len_com`. Если посмотреть по коду, то там формально обновляют переменную `Command`, но ее тип непонятен. Скорее всего это будет строка. Тогда так

```
std::string com = 'commanda';
size_t len_com = com.lenght();
```

Но это уже нужно смотреть по коду. А то строка может оказаться юникодной или ещё чего то там.

Может быть эффективнее будет через массив `char`.

Comment: @KoVadim:

1. `char[] start`?
2. `command.insert(command.end(), start, start + sizeof(start))`?

Comment: 1. у нас же вроде не java? или я плохо читал новый стандарт?
2. а позицию я не приметил. Но вот размер - в данном случае неважно, а в общем случае нужно смотреть. Но вот с sizeof нужно быть поаккуратнее. Пока у нас вектор char - все хорошо, но вдруг завтра туда int будет желание поместить? Почему не добавили append...

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам! Не только указали куда копать, но и дали готовое решение! Слышал об этом сообществе, но не думал что тут могут помочь так!

Comment: И ещё, я могу заменить шестнадцатеричные числа соответствующими десятеричными?

Comment: да, конечно можно. можно даже восьмеричными (для развития, они записываются с начальным нулем. то есть `010` это не 10 (десятичное), а 8 (десятичное)).
Все равно, потом компилятор переведет это в *бинарный формат* (в последовательность нулей и единиц).